# Car dying at low RPM only after filling up with gas

Tags: engine, chrysler, rough-idle

My question is closely related to one about a [Jag dying at low RPM](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/2622/1657), but is slightly different because it only occurs after refueling and because the problem persists after cleaning the throttle body, as suggested by the answers.

The car is a 2006 Chrysler 300C, which occasionally dies at low RPM (e.g. at a stop sign). I can feel the RPM drop suddenly and see it on the tach; if they dip too low the engine dies. If I notice it fast enough I can rev the engine to keep it going. Sometimes the engine RPM will stutter while driving as well, but the engine will typically recover if the RPMs are high enough when it happens.

The problem only occurs shortly after filling up with gas and seems to be more likely the lower the tank was at fill-up, but I don't have much data on that. The problem occurs regardless of octane (87 and 89 are both approved for the Hemi engine) and subsides after several miles of driving, especially if it is not stop-and-go.

Several things have been done (some were just routine maintenance), but none have fixed the problem:

- small leak in transmission fixed
- throttle body cleaned
- induction system serviced
- spark plugs replaced
- replaced fuel filter
- flushed fuel system
- checked out timing sensor

Comment: When you fill do you stop fueling when the pump shuts off or do you give it a little more get it totally full?.Does it occurr if you only fill the tank to 3/4/full?

Comment: @mikes I stop when the pump shuts off; I never top-off the tank. I haven't tried only a partial tank fill. I'm close to full now but will do that next time I fill up and update the question.

Comment: have you checked the fuel filter?

Comment: @warren Yes, see list above, 5th bullet.

Comment: How much did it cost to fix ? Because unfortunately I'm having the same problem?

Comment: @user2891 Several hundred dollars IIRC. See my updated answer below though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A defective ignition switch, which has been [attributed to several deaths](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/27/business/13-deaths-untold-heartache-from-gm-defect.html?_r=0), and caused several models of GM cars to spontaneously shutdown during operations. These reports very accurately describe what we noticed.

**Update:** The dealership said that the purge valve solenoid and vapor canister were contaminated with fuel. That's what they said that was wrong, and we got those parts fixed (several hundred $ IIRC). Unfortunately, the problem resurfaced. By that time we'd moved, so we took the car to a totally different dealership. They also could not reproduce the problem reliably and there was no code on the computer. They called around to a dozen or so other dealerships and ultimately came to the conclusion that the Hemi engines just do not idle well and some of them have a tendency to just shut off.

I don't have corroboration or evidence on this next bit, which is just my speculation, but I suspect that there is just a stack up of various tolerances and timings in the system and gains set in the automatic idle throttle controller in the car's computer that for some engines under some conditions stack up in a way that causes the engine to shut off unpredictably.

**Update 2:** They said there was nothing they could really do to fix it. Ultimately we traded in the car because it became too frustrating to deal with, which was a shame because otherwise it was awesome.

Comment: ..geez...I read your link discussing the ignition switch issue. That's frightening. I've had to replace the ignition switch in my 97 Blazer twice, both times because it just quit starting. But the thought of it failing at speed is insane......mostly because I'm sure the steering would enter that anti-theft locked-up mode. Hopefully braking and shifting would work but I'm sure braking responsiveness would be like 5%, if that. E-brake maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Replace fuses that go to computer shutdown, #11 &14 I think. Or re-seat all fuses in the fuse box under the hood. The spades on the fuses build up a thin corrosion that gives a voltage drop.[they got me for $1200] new computer and new plugs in my 2006 300c

Comment: I no longer have the car to try this on, but hopefully your answer will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may just have a dirty fuel filter and gas tank. Because there's lots of gunk in your gas tank, e.g. sand, rust or other debris, when you have the tank filled, this gets swirled around and sucked up by the fuel pump. As soon as enough of this gunk gets into your fuel filter, it gets blocked. Which is why the car shudders and dies at low RPM. At higher RPM or under load, the pump would apply more force and you'll get more fuel through, but at lower pressures it won't.

Seeing as the filter was replaced and the fuel system flushed, I'd recommend having a peak inside the tank itself. I don't think a fuel system flush includes cleaning out the tank, so it might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with my vauxhall vectra c. 2008 with 1.8 petrol sri engine. always after fueling. no matter what fuel or where it was bought.and it was just after an engine rebuild with faulty camshaft timing oil valves that made her throw and bend a valve.

i also ended up with 3 engine codes. cruise control. engine trim and enigine misfire code.
I changed all parts that I could think of. plugs. oil. fuel filter etc

i finally cleaned the mass air flow sensor gently with a dry tooth brush. (between the air box and throttle). (do not recommend this, far better to get a new for for £25 from dealers)
and as if by magic. all codes and fueling problem went away.
fingers crossed it stays that way :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect a evaporative system issue. It could be something as stupid as seal on a fuel cap. I used to have the same issue with a 2001 Carolla. I changed the cap with a OEM  cap and the problem rectified itself. When fueling up stop after the first click on the fuel nozzle. Overfilling by a little amount can cause to happen. What if any codes where there ?